# Cant load pretrained model to generate embeddings

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I am using this code to generate sentence embeddings with the hugging face transformer library, and I am getting this error. I can't seem to resolve this problem. Any pointers will help. Thanks.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

#Mean Pooling - Take attention mask into account for correct averaging
def mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output[0] #First element of model_output contains all token embeddings
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1) / torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)


# Sentences we want sentence embeddings for
sentences = ['This is an example sentence', 'Each sentence is converted']

# Load model from HuggingFace Hub
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/all-roberta-large-v1')
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/all-roberta-large-v1')

# Tokenize sentences
encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

# Compute token embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input)

# Perform pooling
sentence_embeddings = mean_pooling(model_output, encoded_input['attention_mask'])

# Normalize embeddings
sentence_embeddings = F.normalize(sentence_embeddings, p=2, dim=1)

print("Sentence embeddings:")
print(sentence_embeddings)
```

```
print(torch.__version__)

>> 1.4.0
```

**I am getting the below error.**

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py
> in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args,
> **kwargs)    1434                 try:
> -> 1435                     state_dict = torch.load(resolved_archive_file, map_location="cpu")    1436
> except Exception as e:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in
> load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
> 526         if _is_zipfile(opened_file):
> --> 527             with _open_zipfile_reader(f) as opened_zipfile:
> 528                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in
> **init**(self, name_or_buffer)
> 223     def **init**(self, name_or_buffer):
> --> 224         super(_open_zipfile_reader, self).**init**(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
> 225
>
> RuntimeError: version_ <= kMaxSupportedFileFormatVersion INTERNAL
> ASSERT FAILED at ..\caffe2\serialize\inline_container.cc:132, please
> report a bug to PyTorch. Attempted to read a PyTorch file with version
> 3, but the maximum supported version for reading is 2. Your PyTorch
> installation may be too old. (init at
> ..\caffe2\serialize\inline_container.cc:132) (no backtrace available)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_31400/3667175826.py in 
> ----> 1 model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/all-roberta-large-v1')
> 2
> 3 # Tokenize sentences
> 4 encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')
> 5
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py
> in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args,
> **kwargs)
> 445         elif type(config) in cls._model_mapping.keys():
> 446             model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
> --> 447             return model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path,
> *model_args, config=config, **kwargs)
> 448         raise ValueError(
> 449             f"Unrecognized configuration class {config.**class**} for this kind of AutoModel: {cls.**name**}.\n"
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py
> in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args,
> **kwargs)    1437                     try:    1438                         with open(resolved_archive_file) as f:
> -> 1439                             if f.read().startswith("version"):    1440                                 raise OSError(    1441
> "You seem to have cloned a repository without having git-lfs
> installed. Please install "
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input,
> final)
> 21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
> 22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
> ---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
> 24
> 25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
>
> MemoryError:

Comment: Update your torch package.